# Blocked from replying to questions

Tags: support, post-ban

I've been blocked (for a month) from replying to any question on Stack Overflow, for replying to lots of questions in a short period.

Do you know how to unblock this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: [There is a FAQ topic here on meta about this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) Check it out, there are even tips on how to fix it. :) (Do note that this FAQ covers both questions and answers, so don't be thrown off!)

Comment: Those must have been some pretty poor answers. This is evidenced by saying you are "replying" to the questions. You shouldn't reply, you need to *answer*.

Comment: recommended reading: [answer]

Comment: What is the *exact* message you receive? If you have an answer ban there is no time limit, so the *for a month* part is surprising.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I imagine that the OP meant that he has been blocked for a month so far, not realizing that than ban has no time limit.

Comment: @psubsee2003: ah, of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've had a number of posts deleted lately. There is a moderator message I've just sent you that explains why they were deleted.

Comment: so can i had my account working back?! i accept your agreements

Comment: I want to get unblock too.I was a beginner and wasn't thought of the how the reaction would be. I tried correcting post but faced the same issue. Thought of deleting the post would solve the problem. But, i now understand. Can't ask any more question. Pl unblock me :(